# SSL and domain with WWW or without WWW

Tags: ssl, iis-6

why does my ssl work only for domain.co.il and not for www.domain.co.il
is it like i read, that we need to order the SSL twice?

and what can be done about it, if this is the truth? how can it be redirected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need two SSL certs one for www.domain.co.il and one for domain.co.il or you need one cert which has both names.  We use certs from GoDaddy which when purchasing domain.co.il also includes www.domain.co.il automatically.

Comment: Agreed.  This is probably the best way to go.  If you use the other suggestions you'll be leaving out one of the addresses.  The WWW or the one without WWW.  This way you catch both.

Comment: I think GeoTrust have started to do this too. You buy the one without www and get the one with www included.

Answer (score 1):

A wildcard certificate should work with any subdomain but do you really need both? Just tell your users http://domain.com and get the http to redirect to https://domain.com. Then setup http://www.domain.com to also redirect to https://domain.com If your users try http://www.domain.com it will still work and they probably wont do https://www.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a wild card SSL in order to do that!

Comment: UCC certs allow you to name multiple SANs and are almost universally cheaper than wildcard certs.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of two things.

1) A wildcard certificate for your domain.co.il domain.

2) A certificate that uses the 'subjectAltName' extension, and list all the alternate host names that your server uses (like www.domain.co.il and domain.co.il).

The one place I know sells certificates with the 'subjectAltName' extension is Verisign.  There might be others.